# Azure Batch Service: Job and Task do not run in all nodes in 4 Server Pool

Tags: azure, azure-batch, windows-server-2022

I'm using the Azure Batch Service to conduct load tests. I want to create a pool of machines that will run my load test application.

I created a Batch Service. Then I created an application pool with 1 Windows server. I uploaded and configured an application. The application simulates a load. I created one job which has one task that looks like this.

`cmd /c "cd /d %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_LiveLoadTest#1.0% && %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_LiveLoadTest#1.0%\LiveLoadTest.exe -d900 -s17"`

The application runs correctly and yields valid results.

I created another application pool with 4 Windows servers. I assigned the same application to that pool. I created the same job and task.

Only one node in that pool received the application and ran the job. The other 3 nodes were idle. Shouldn't the application install on all nodes and run the job automatically? Why were the other 3 nodes idle? I see no errors in any logs.

I attached an image to show the situation. Is this a bug in the Azure Batch Service portal UI?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add multiple tasks to your job.

If you create 4 tasks they will be distributed on your 4 nodes.